# Ajax Push Engine

Tags: webserver, html, ajax-push

I'm researching methods to find ways for an event driven web application where a server can push data to the web page. Can I use APE ?? If so how can I use it and some resources please??

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have been writing event driven servers since the dawn of the network. A simple google search will find your way.

However, since the client is a browser, your server must re-act upon keeping an HTTP connection open instead of simply doing socket work.

This is basically the only small difference than say an IRC server or a [simple chat server](http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-hacks/1999-December/000217.html).